# null pointer exception at AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng, ui-automation

**Getting an error for test NG**

Error Log:

```
    [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.features(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45
```

My Test Runner settings:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target_json/cucumber.json",
        "junit:taget_junit/cucumber.xml", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter"
        }
features = "C:\\AutomationNeon1\\atom\\src\\main\\features\\smascheduler\\new-schedule.feature", glue = {
                "com.morrisons.automation.stepdefs.sma" })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think it is not able to find the feature file. Check the features path. Try with starting the features path from src.

Comment: Just curious why in the stack trace TestNG is mentioned and in your configuration it's jUnit

Comment: @EugeneS  junit plugin produces xml reports which CI servers use to generate fancy reports...

Comment: Can you please let us know what version of `cucumber-testng` library you are working with ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was duplicate step definition methods, it got fixed when i removed duplicate method. i have ignored Junit logs, and it was printed in the same.